# She can sing really well, but when addressing rivals, he behaves like a bully. Who?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

She's well known in her industry, frequently breaking records with her voice.

She tries to be a loving and caring person, but she doesn't let anyone push her around.

She keeps him locked away, for the sake of her enemies. He bullies her enemies, making them wish they just payed their rent and stayed in their place. He never stops, even when their careers are laying lifeless and cold in a bow-tied coffin, buried deep within the dirt. Sightings of him have become far less frequent, due to the backlash she receives when she lets him loose.

The industry doesn't like it when she defends herself. She could be subject to a physical attack from one of her rivals, and still, her industry will find a way to blame her for it.

Who is she? And who is he? Explain your answer please.

EDIT:

A hint:

> If he was Harambe, he'd be dead.

EDIT:

Another hint:

> She has worked with Rihanna.

Answer (score 2):

I'll hazard a guess...

> **[Nicki Minaj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicki_Minaj) and her angry male alter-ego [Roman Zolanski](http://nickiminaj.wikia.com/wiki/Roman_Zolanski)**

Why:

> She's a well-known singer who's [collaborated with Rihanna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly_(Nicki_Minaj_song)) and broke hip-hop Billboard records. Also got into a physical altercation with Cardi B, if I'm not mistaken (who threw a shoe at her). She definitely [tries to show she cares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicki_Minaj#Philanthropy), but is also extremely assertive and outspoken in her art. And Roman's her angry, wild, gay male alter-ego who attacks her enemies, but she eventually retired him. I'll probably have to delve deeper into her songs [which I rarely do TBH ;)] to get that Harambe reference, though.

And just to corroborate that:

> In her first and one of her more famous songs as Roman, [*Roman's Revenge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman%27s_Revenge), Roman states: **"Now I'ma wrap your coffin with a bow."**

Answer (score 1):

On a wild guess, is it

> Rihanna? (and Chris Brown)

*She's well known in her industry, frequently breaking records with her voice.*

> She's won a ton of awards: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_awards_and_nominations_received_by_Rihanna

*She tries to be a loving and caring person, but she doesn't let anyone push her around.*

> She has a very strong/fierce stage personality

*She keeps him locked away, for the sake of her enemies. He bullies her enemies, making them wish they just payed their rent and stayed in their place. He never stops, even when their careers are laying lifeless and cold in a bow-tied coffin, buried deep within the dirt. Sightings of him have become far less frequent, due to the backlash she receives when she lets him loose.
The industry doesn't like it when she defends herself. She could be subject to a physical attack from one of her rivals, and still, her industry will find a way to blame her for it.*

> I feel like this is referring to Chris Brown, who was convicted of physically assaulting her

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm afraid this is incorrect, but I'll give you another hint (see edit to question).

Comment: Also, FYI, Rihanna doesn't keep Chris Brown locked away (unfortunately) - he's still out here, making 45-track long albums.

Comment: Unfortunately the Chris Brown - Rihanna thing is all I really know about that part of the music world, so I wouldn't be able to hazard a guess even with the second hint

Answer (score 1):

Is it...

> Lady Gaga?

If he was Harambe, he'd be dead.

> She wore a meat dress.

She tries to be a loving and caring person, but she doesn't let anyone push her around.

> She's very compassionate, but also defends herself.

She's well known in her industry, frequently breaking records with her voice.

> Won 6 Grammies. Outstanding voice.

Comment: Hello Bogdan, welcome to PuzzlingSE! I like the answer, but I'm not 100% convinced whether it's the right one - too many hints don't quite check out (yet). Maybe you can improve your answer by refering to the other parts of the riddle and explain, how your answer appplies to them? Anyway, enjoy your stay here! :-)